# Is it ever ok to temporarily disable Android back button?

Tags: android, back-button, disabled-control

I have an activity that I deep link into that normally would be deep into a stack of activities.

When the activity starts up the first thing it does is make a potentially long running asynchronous call to fetch some data.

The data that is being fetched is necessary to know what activity should be launched when the user clicks the Up or back button from the current activity.

The issue I'm running into is that if the user clicks the back button before the data has returned I have no idea of knowing which Activity I should launch as the proper Activity stack is dependent on having the data that I'm fetching.

An easy way around this is to intercept the onBackPressed() call and if I don't have the data I need I can just ignore the back press, however this seems like an obvious bad idea as I'm changing the behavior of the system UI.

Alternatively I could note that onBackPressed() had been called and once the data returns I could finish() the current activity and launch the correct activity however in this case there's a chance that the user clicks the button and has to wait awhile for the data to return so there would be a noticeable delay in them pressing the back button and the app actually executing the back move.

Any ideas on an elegant way to solve this?

Comment: If this is really the case (i.e. you can’t avoid this async call to know which activity must be launched) I would show a progress dialog upon the first back press, and then automatically go back once you have your data. I must say though that this data should possibly be encoded in the deep link url.

Comment: Why is the activity stack dependent on the data being fetched? Can you explain this a bit more? Can't you just go back to whatever the previous Activity would have been assuming the data is unreachable?

Comment: This is part of a login flow where there can be multiple ways of logging in. If the user has logged in before they are brought to their preferred login activity. However, once in that activity they are able to hit the back button. If the user has multiple login options then they should be brought to an activity that shows the multiple options. If they only have one login option then they should be brought to a different activity where they'd need to enter some identifying information. The way I make that choice is by looking at a complex business object that has to be fetched from db

Answer (score 4):

I think **you should avoid preventing the user to leave your app** as Users don't like feeling "trapped" inside your app, or maybe more unexperienced users will think that you app freezed the phone.

Now in your case I suggest to override `onBackPressed`  as you are already doing but with a message that let's user know that download is not finished yet, and move your **download in background** and meanwhile show a **temp actvity which just states that data are loading**, maybe with a nice progressbar.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //Show a dialog with yes or no option or other options, and if user 
    // answers yes call super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Hope it helps :)!

Comment: This is standard practice, tbh, if I came across such app, I never open it again due to such bad UX I get, and maybe all users feel the same - not like being forced. Worst case, they uninstall app.